# Removing duplicate lines from all but one of set of files?

Tags: shell, scripting

I'd like to be able to feed multiple text files to some command, and have the duplicate lines removed from all but one of the files... any ideas?

To clarify - I mean I don't want any duplicate lines between *any* of the files.

So, if file #1 had "A", "B", and "C", and file #2 had "C", "D", and "E", I'm looking for code that will get rid of the "C" in file #2, but not file #1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
for f in ${FILES}; do
    # skip THE_FILE
    if [ "${f}" = "THE_FILE" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    # remove duplicate lines
    cat "${f}" | sort | uniq > "${f}".dedup
done
```

Comment: I may be following your code wrong, but I don't think I made myself clear, so I updated my post with an example.

Comment: How big are the files? Do you add new files periodically or it should be a one time shot?

Comment: 10 to 30gb each. It would be a one off thing, so it doesn't matter if it takes a while. But I want the method to work with more than two files, so merging and sorting and splitting seems like a bad idea. Instead of removing duplicates from all but one file, the other thing that could happen is any duplicates get removed from *all* files and inserted into their own duplicates.txt file... would that be easier?

Comment: Few 30GB files it is a bit too much for a script IMO. We can either come up with sort + uniq or similar solution, which might take a lot of memory, or we could use disk (i.e. VERY slow).